# Querying a database/REST API

Tags: qgis, api, mapping, rest

I cannot figure out how to use QGIS to query the database at this link: https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/swdiws

Comment: If it's a non-standard interface there's likly not to be a standard way of doing it.

Comment: severe weather can be consumed in QGIS using https://idpgis.ncep.noaa.gov/arcgis/rest/services

Comment: At the link below it seems the closest I'm getting to watch/warning data, but it seems like it only has current weather watches and warnings, and I'm looking for archived. Any idea? https://idpgis.ncep.noaa.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NWS_Forecasts_Guidance_Warnings/watch_warn_adv/MapServer

Answer (score 2):

The API is nicely documented, so using it in QGIS is straightforward. Here's a snippet of PyQGIS code that displays tornadoes from June 6-7, 2005:

```
import requests
url = "https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/swdiws/geojson/nx3tvs/20050601:20050607"
r_sub = requests.get(url)
vslayer = QgsVectorLayer(r_sub.text, "NOAA", "ogr")
vfeatures = vslayer.getFeatures()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vslayer)
```

Copy and paste it into a QGIS Python Console editor window:
[image]

Comment: When I replace nx3tvs with warn, it doesn't work. Any idea why? This url for example has data at it, but nothing shows up on the map, even when it goes to the layer panel: https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/swdiws/geojson/warn/20070505:20070506

Comment: The returned GeoJSON for /warn/ may not be correctly formed-- maybe a JSON expert can chime in.